# python - Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, heroku

I am deploying a python script at `heroku`, which will make a request to another server after every `3 minutes`.

Deployment is going good but when i see the `logs`, I got these `errors`.

```
2016-11-01T07:42:12.919755+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python script.py --log-file -`
2016-11-01T07:43:13.097413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-11-01T07:43:13.097556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-11-01T07:43:13.196156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-11-01T07:43:13.212942+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-11-01T07:43:13.213858+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-11-01T07:43:16.719828+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python script.py --log-file -`
2016-11-01T07:44:17.215381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-11-01T07:44:17.215381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-11-01T07:44:17.364708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-11-01T07:44:17.367610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

`Procfile`

```
web: python script.py --log-file -
```

`script.py`

```
import sys
import requests
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=3)
def timed_job():
    try:
        request = requests.get(url='https://royal-tag-services.herokuapp.com/api/sms-service/scheduler/')
    except Exception as e:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'scheduler request failed'

sched.start()
```

`Result of 'tree -L 1' command`

```
├── Procfile
├── requirements.txt
├── script.py
└── supporterenv
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Replace "web" with "worker" in your Procfile.

Comment: I thought it is working. But this is what i got when i see the erros.                           2016-11-01T08:22:20.356683+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 96b1efe by adil.azeem@mezino.com
2016-11-01T08:22:20.356782+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by adil.azeem@mezino.com
2016-11-01T08:22:20.422315+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2016-11-01T08:22:20.572330+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-11-01T08:22:20.572340+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished

Comment: If you have a "web" process type in your Procfile, the dyno running that process must bind to its assigned $PORT within 60 seconds (by default), in order to be able to respond to incoming web requests over http/s. If it doesn't, Heroku takes down the dyno as explained in  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout.

Since your python script is not a web server, the entry for it in the Procfile should not be defined as a "web" process type.

Comment: In my case, though it worked after replacing "web" with "worker", but it came up with another issue that "at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" ", is there a solution to avoiding both of them?

Comment: @MemphisMeng "at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" this means you don't have any running web dynos first run `heroku ps:scale web=1` then open your app

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch What is you have a process that needs to have access to HTTP but are still getting the error? In my case I am using selenium library in my python script.

Comment: NOTE: you need to run `heroku ps:scale worker=1` since workers are not scaled automatically (and you should run `heroku ps:scale web=0` to remove the web cpu)